# ngx-fullpage - how to access angular variables inside OnLeave?

Tags: angular, fullpage.js

I've this...

```
<div mnFullpage [mnFullpageOnLeave]="onLeave">
 <div class="section welcome-section fp-section fp-table" *ngFor="let p of this.content.pages">
<div class="fp-tableCell">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="contentLayer">
      Content goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MnFullpageService } from 'ngx-fullpage';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-main-page',
 templateUrl: './mainPage.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./mainPage.component.scss']
})
export class MainPageComponent {
readonly content = Content
pageIndex: number = 0;
constructor(public fullpageService: MnFullpageService) {

}
onLeave(index: number, nextIndex: object, direction: string): void {
   this.pageIndex = nextIndex.index;
}
}
```

The problem is...when I set the variable pageIndex inside the onLeave...this is not reflecting. Any suggestion ?

Comment: are you adding the arguments required for onLeave to work properly? or even calling the function on `mnFullpageOnLeave` you would need to have `onLeave(index, nextIndex, direction)`

Comment: I don't know about ngx-fullpage but you might want to use the official Angular wrapper for fullPage.js: [angular-fullpage](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/angular-fullpage) which is maintained and updated with the latest fullPage.js version.

Comment: Yes, @Alvaro ! That's what I did yesterday..Gave up from this ngx-full page and now I am actually using your official angular wrapper ! Very good work , mate !

Comment: Glad it helped @MarcoJr!